# How to change variables within the same function. Javascript

Tags: javascript

**I want to change an input value by clicking on a div** + adding a CSS effect . The issue is that I got 10 divs. I can do it by making a function for each one of them but i´m pretty sure that there is a much better way to do it **without repeating the code**. I´m starting at this, so it would be great if i could get some help.

I got an input and a few divs with just numbers:

```
 <input type="text" id="screen" dir="rtl"/>
 <div class="key" id="tres">3</div>
 <div class="key" id="dos">2</div>
 <div class="key" id="uno">1</div>
 ...
```

And then the function:

```
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
var uno = document.getElementById("uno");

uno.onclick=function to () {
    screen.value+=uno.innerHTML;
    uno.style.boxShadow="none";
    setTimeout(function() {
        uno.style.boxShadow="0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
    }, 220);
}
```

Now what i want to do is to **use the same ".onclick" function on every single div**, not in my newbie way (re writting the function and changing variables) but in a practical one. I've been trying with "classname" instead of "id". I´ve attempted with ".replace" by trying to replace the value names. And actually im trying with something like this:

```
 var hell=["uno","dos","tres"];
    var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
    for (var i = 0; i < hell.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(hell[i]).onclick=function to() {
            screen.value+=document.getElementById(hell[i]).innerHTML;
        }
    }
```

I barely know what I´m doing so a little bit of enlightenment would be grateful (avoiding jQuery if possible).

Thanks a lot! (Sorry about my bad English)

Comment: You can use  `document.getElementById(hell[i]).addEventListener('click', function to() {
  screen.value+= Number(this.textContent);
 });`

Comment: @bergi, Closure is surely a solution, but Problem can also be solved without uisng it

Comment: I don't think that the answer will be understood @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the elements by class name, attach an eventListener to each of the elements, and you'll get what you wanted.

```js
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('key'));

elements.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', fn));

function fn(e) {
  screen.value = (parseInt(screen.value, 10) || 0) + parseInt(e.target.innerText, 10);
  elements.forEach(el => el.style.boxShadow = "none");
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.target.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
  }, 220);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="screen" dir="rtl" />
<div class="key" id="tres">3</div>
<div class="key" id="dos">2</div>
<div class="key" id="uno">1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Basically, instead of getting each one by ID, you can get all of them in an array by getting them by their class (since they all have the same class).

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('screen');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.key');

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.onclick = function() {
    myInput.value += input.innerHTML;
    // everything else goes here
  }
});
```

See [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrzZyb) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

### ES6

Here is a more optimal solution to your problem. It may seem a bit obscure if you don't know new ES6 syntax, but since you want to learn anyway, here it goes:

```js
let screenValue = 0,
    lastClickedDiv;

const screen = document.getElementById('screen'),
      keys   = [...document.getElementsByClassName('key')];

const toggleBoxShadow = (clickedDiv) => {
  if (clickedDiv !== lastClickedDiv) {
    clickedDiv.classList.add('active');
    if (lastClickedDiv !== undefined) {
      lastClickedDiv.classList.remove('active');
    }
    lastClickedDiv = clickedDiv;
  }
};
const keysClickListener = (event) => {
  screenValue += parseInt(event.target.textContent);
  screen.value = screenValue;
  setTimeout(() => toggleBoxShadow(event.target), 220);
};

keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('click', keysClickListener));
```

```css
.key.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
        inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="screen" dir="rtl"/>
<div class="key">3</div>
<div class="key">2</div>
<div class="key">1</div>
```

- `[...document.getElementsByClassName('key')]` gets all elements with class name `key` and turns that collection into an array using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).
- `keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('click', keysClickListener))` adds click listener named `keysClickListener` to each element of `keys` array.
- `keysClickListener` function updates `screenValue` counter by adding number from clicked div to value it already stores and sets that as `#screen`'s value. Then it invokes `toggleBoxShadow()` after 220 ms.

If you want anything else explained, let me know.